# VisualCode - Change Font Color for Custom Word

Tags: visual-studio-code

i'm searching for a way to change Font Color for certain Word in Visual Studio Code 2017.

Eg. in the Last Period i'm using a lot Angular. It will be cool if i can change `angular` word color in editor to differentiate from other constant and variable.

If you know a way please tell me!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TODO-highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight) could work for that.  Not its intended use but you can create and easily color any word you want the extension to highlight.  It was originally intended for highlighting TODO and FIXME, for example, but you could create an "angular" highlight.