# VSCode: Change color of print()

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the color of print statements in VSCode (the whole line)? Something like the following, but ONLY for print statements and for the whole print line as well:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "{print statements}": "#555555"
},
```

I use a lot of print statements in my code, and want to make them less obtrusive - so trying to change them to a less visible color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [TODO-highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight) as suggested in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054338/visualcode-change-font-color-for-custom-word)